# Format date without year

Tags: datetime

Using `\formatdate` from `datetime`, I can get a date properly formatted in multiple languages:

```
\formatdate{3}{4}{2012}
```

However, I would like to only use the day and month and leave the year behind. I've tried passing:

```
\formatdate{3}{4}{\empty}
```

but it doesn't work, as it expects a number.

How could I achieve that?

Comment: This is because [`datetime`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime) stores the day/month/year in counters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\makeatletter

\def\formatdateny{\csname noyear\languagename\expandafter\endcsname\formatdate}
\def\noyearenglish#1, \the\@year{#1}
\let\noyearamerican\noyearenglish
\let\noyearbritish\noyearenglish
\def\noyearfrench#1\space\number\@year{#1}
\let\noyeargerman\noyearfrench
\let\noyearaustrian\noyeargerman
\let\noyearswedish\noyearfrench
\let\noyearbreton\noyearfrench
\def\noyearrussian#1\ \number\@year~\cyrg.{#1}
\def\noyearspanish#1\ de~\number\@year{#1}
\let\noyearcatalan\noyearspanish
\def\noyearbasque#1\number\@year.eko\space{#1}
% etc.

\makeatother


 \formatdateny{3}{4}{2012}
```