# datetime: date without year

Tags: datetime

This question is similar to [Format date without year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71446/format-date-without-year), but I can't deduce the answers. I would like to delete the year in a date,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
\begin{document}
I have: \today
I want: 15 de diciembre
I have: \longdate\today
I want: lunes 15 de diciembre
\end{document}
```

as I use babel-spanish, is enough in this language, but in other language can be useful for other people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`datetime` provides the `\newdateformat` command for just such cases:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
\newdateformat{myshort}{%
    \THEDAY\ de \monthname[\THEMONTH]%
    }
\newdateformat{mylong}{%
    \dayofweekname{\THEDAY}{\THEMONTH}{\THEYEAR} 
    \THEDAY\ de \monthname[\THEMONTH]%
    }
\begin{document}
I have: \today

I now have: \myshort\today

I want: 15 de diciembre

I have: \longdate\today

I now have: \mylong\today

I want: lunes 15 de diciembre
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This solution is more add-hoc to the package datetime. You just need to add a symbol % after [\THE MONTH], in both commands, because it adds a small space. If you write a period after the command, you can see it clearly.

Comment: @Gitano Fixed :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't speak any kind of Spanish, but this purely revolves around an update to `\formatdate`. Below I've supplied `\noyeardate` which removes the year from being output. Additionally, it prepends `de` to the month name:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}

\makeatletter
\let\oldmonthname\monthname
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\longdate}{%
  \renewcommand*{\formatdate}[3]{%
    \ifshowdow\dayofweekname{##1}{##2}{##3} \fi
    \@day=##1\relax\@month=##2\relax\@year=##3\relax
    \ordinaldate{\the\@day}\ \monthname[\@month]}%, \the\@year}%
  \renewcommand{\monthname}{de \oldmonthname}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\noyeardate}{%
  \renewcommand*{\formatdate}[3]{%
    \@day=##1\relax\@month=##2\relax\@year=##2\relax
    \number\@day~de \monthname[\@month]}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noyeardate
I have: \today

I want: 15 de diciembre

\bigskip

I have: \longdate\today

I want: lunes 15 de diciembre

\end{document}
```