# How is \longdate defined in datetime

Tags: babel, datetime

I would like to define my own date format similarly to `\longdate` or `\shortdate` with the `datetime` package such that it automatically changes based on the language selected for the `babel` package.

Therefore I would like to know how `\longdate` or `\shortdate` is defined to modify it accordingly.

I want exactly the same behavior as `\shortdate` but without the day of the week **and without the year**. (The solutions in [datetime: date without year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218162/datetime-date-without-year) would not work for German I think. I think https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71449/128042 could (partially) solve my problem, but I don't understand the code so I cannot modify it, so it still would be nice to see the definition of `\shortdate`)

E.g. I want today to be displayed as "17<sup>th</sup> Feb" if `english` is the selected language and as "17. Februar" if `ngerman` is selected as language.

I am slightly disappointed that `\ordinaldate{17}` produces "17" in the case of `ngerman`, while a ordinal numbers is written as "17." in German [(see Wikipedia)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zahlwort#Ordinalzahlen_in_der_Schrift). (Is there a more complete version of `\ordinaldate` that also supports other languages than English, Breton, Welsh and French? I guess someone had to implement already a version of `\ordinaldate` that supports `ngerman` since `\today` is able to print the "." correctly?)

Edit: actually `\longdate` also struggles with the correct formatting of German dates, but the standard format of dates does it correctly. How is this standard format defined?

Comment: Wouldn't `datetime2` be better?

Comment: If you have the `datetime` package on your computer then search for `datetime.sty` which defines all the code used/provided by the package. On my Ubuntu system I used `kpsewhich datetime.sty` to get its location.